# Magento 2 : How to get cart id?

Tags: magento2, cart, api

I am trying to learn swagger in magento 2.

In core APIs of Magento 2 there is a required field `cart_id`.

[image]

[image]

I don't know what is this cart id and how can i find this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Cart id it means Quote id you will get quote Id in your Database Under "quote" table 
It seems you want payment information use the below API 
try this for payment method :

67 is my quote Id : In your case you will get under Quote Table

GET  : your-domain-url/index.php/rest/V1/carts/67/payment-methods

you will get the below resonse
response : [ { "code": "checkmo", "title": "Check / Money order" } ]*

Comment: sorry Ankit but there is no field name as quote id in table quote ? can you explain plz

Comment: i see quote_id in quote_payment table i use quote id in browser url as you suggest but nothing is showing.  Just this msg is showing <message>Consumer is not authorized to access %resources</message>

Comment: give me compete url what you are using so i will tell you ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/magento/2.1/index.php/rest/V1/carts/261/payment-methods.  where 261 is quote id from quote_payment table

Comment: Sorry its on quote Table :filed name : "entity_id"

Comment: yes you are using correct what response you are getting i am getting the correct response please check your quote table "entity_id" is same as you are providing in url

Comment: yes it is same but still it is not working

Comment: please provide response are you using GET or POST ?

Comment: refer this screen as well http://screencast.com/t/sqcaY5ATJOHR

Comment: i am using get method

Comment: 1. please provide response here      2. Did you checked my provided screenshot ?

Comment: yes i checked your screenshot i am doing the same wait i show you my screenshot

Comment: i  Have updated the question plz check @Ankit.

Comment: You are doing correct . but you did not authorized you have to do authorization first then only it will work  . Do you know how to do authorization or you did already ?

Comment: Reference : http://screencast.com/t/IBSjHIOlbwP1

Comment: no i don't know how to do this. From where i will get consumer key and secret ?

Comment: Go system => Integration => New Integration & Generate the key & follow the below URL all generated key you have to validate with POSTman or whatever you are using http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html

Comment: Thank you @Ankit for your help. Really its help me alot . I will check it later if there is any query i will ask.

Comment: Great Finally you Did :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;
}

function testFunction(){
    $cartID = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you come here for a bigger cart_id(something like 1WxKm8WUm3uFKXLlHXezew5WREfVRPAn, not a simple number). Then that is masked_id. You can find this value in table quote_id_mask.

Also, `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory` can be used to get masked_id.

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->_jsonHelper->jsonDecode($this->getRequest()->getContent());
    $maskedQuoteId = $data['quoteId'];
    $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($maskedQuoteId, 'masked_id');
    $quoteId = $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get the `cart_id`

```
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$cart_id=$cart->getQuote()->getId();
```

Comment: You should not use the objectManager.

Comment: @vitoriodachef Why? Is it a flaw

Comment: @VishalParkash it prevents all the benefits of dependency injection thus making the code more rigid and sometimes impossible to cover using unit tests. I urge you to search for the benefits of DI on your own, it will make more sense once you take a look at it.